# how can i make space between rows without interruption in it's borders?

Tags: html, css

I have two rows in an html table like this :

[image: Desired output]

and in number one you can see that i made the borders, which i do not want to interrupt. but as shown in number two i want to add some space between the buttons in each row, without affecting the borders, what is the property i can use to do this?

here is my html :

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td width="188px" class="button" ><img src="b2.png" /></td>
   <td width="188px" class="button" ></td>
   <td width="188px" class="button" ></td>
   <td width="188px" class="button" ></td>
   <td width="188px" class="button" ><img src="b1.png" /></td>
   <td width="188px" class="button" ></td>
 </tr>
<table>
```

here is my css code :

```
table {
     border-collapse: collapse;  
    }
table td {
     margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
     padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
     border-left:1.0px solid #000;
     border-right:1.0px solid #000;
     border-spacing:5px;
    }


/*button class */

.button {
    width:180px;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgb(51,153,51);
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    margin-left:1px;
    margin-right:12px;
     /* add this */
}
.button a{
    display:block;
    height:37px;
    color:white;
    line-height:100px;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}
.button:before {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    width:180px;
    height:37px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:100%;
    transition:all 0.5s;
}
.button:hover:before {
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: You already asked the question, and I already gave you the soution + a working jsFiddle here: y-i-cant-see-borders-for-columns-in-this-table-row/24594729#comment38105953_24594729

Comment: i asked this question before not after .. can you remove the un vote please i don't want to get blocked

Answer (score 0):

It looks like none of these properties are working properly directly on the table elements. If you add a `<div>` with class `button` inside the columns like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="188px">
        <div class="button">
            <img src="b2.png" />
        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="188px">
        <div class="button"></div>
    </td>
    <td width="188px">
        <div class="button"></div>
    </td>
    <td width="188px">
        <div class="button"></div>
    </td>
    <td width="188px">
        <div class="button">
            <img src="b1.png" />
        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="188px">
        <div class="button"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

then `padding` and `margin` will work as expected.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Rg6J/1/)

Comment: @user3675605  it was a typo. if you don't want the button to extend change the margin instead `margin: 0px 0px 1px 0px;`

Comment: @user3675605 it looks like none of these properties are working properly directly on the table elements. If you add a `<div>` inside the columns like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4Rg6J/1/) then it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

try to put `</br>` after each `</td>`

Answer (score 0):

```
table td {
 margin-top: 10px; // change the value from 10 to whichever you like
 margin-bottom: 10px; // same as above
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 border-left:1.0px solid #000;
 border-right:1.0px solid #000;
 border-spacing:5px;
}
```

Can you also post the .button class??